# Create column by adding columns using a condition

Tags: python, pandas, variables, addition, jupyter

I would like to add a new column to an existing data frame where I will show the sum of the values within the other columns except I do not want to include one of the column names which I have assigned as a variable.

For example,

ignore = 'Column3'

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
1        4       2
2        10      2
3        15      1
```

I want to create a new column and add only Column1 with column however as you can see I have `ignore = 'Column3'` as a variable, is there a way I can add the columns up in a code however incorporate the variable `ignore` so that whatever column is used in the ignore variable will not be added in the calculation?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. PLease provide a sample output to help clarify your question, as well as what you've tried so far. See the following link: [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can use:

```
ignore='Column3'
df['New']=df.loc[:,df.columns!=ignore].sum(axis=1)
print(df)

   Column1  Column2  Column3  New
0        1        4        2    5
1        2       10        2   12
2        3       15        1   18
```

Or if you want a list of columns to be ignored:

```
ignore=['Column3']
df['New']=df.loc[:,df.columns.difference(ignore)].sum(axis=1)
print(df)

   Column1  Column2  Column3  New
0        1        4        2    5
1        2       10        2   12
2        3       15        1   18
```

Comment: I tried this however the sum of the columns excluding column3 is coming out inaccurately :(

Comment: @RSem can you explain, the sum is right in front of you. 4+1 = 5. If any other logic, please explain, also posting your desired output would help people be even more clearer.